# Models incorrectly try to be replaced instead of update

Tags: php, phalcon

I try to update the name of a user `id=1`. I tried following code (v 1.3). But instead of updating, it try to relace the user and `var_dump($n->getMessages());` output error relating to `not null` attributes.

```
 class UserApi extends Phalcon\DI\Injectable{}

 $n=new User;
$n->id=1;
 $n->name='Tom';
 $n->save(); //or even $n->update()
```

`User::findFirst(1)->save();` works. But I need to use a single code for bothe  create and update operations.

Comment: Can you please add the exact error message you get?

Comment: @natronite There is no error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want phalcon to do an update and not an insert you have to load the model from the database before changing its properties.

To use the same code for both the create and update operations simply do the following.

```php
$user = User::findFirst($userId);

if (!$user) {
    // Create new user
    $user = new User();
    $user->id = $userId;
}

// Set/update values
$user->name = $userName;
$user->save();
```

Hope this helps.